# Application crashes from command line but runs fine from Unity

Tags: unity, launcher, pidgin

**General question**: How can I most closely mimic via the terminal the way in which Unity executes a program?

I'm able to successfully run pidgin (2.10.3) from the Unity interface (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS), but when I simply run 'pidgin' from the command line I receive a segfault. Ideally, I would like to run 'pidgin' from the command line with the '-d' (debug) flag to see debug output. I thought perhaps Unity was using some special flags, etc. but the standard /usr/share/applications/pidgin.desktop file simply says:

> ```
> [Desktop Entry] 
> Name=Pidgin Internet Messenger 
> GenericName=Internet Messenger 
> Comment=Chat over IM.  Supports AIM, Google Talk, Jabber/XMPP, MSN, Yahoo and more 
> Exec=pidgin 
> Icon=pidgin
> StartupNotify=true 
> Terminal=false 
> Type=Application
> Categories=Network;InstantMessaging; 
> X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=pidgin
> ```

---

Segfault text:

> ```
> ** (Pidgin:12897): WARNING **: Could not connect: Connection refused
>
> (Pidgin:12897): LIBDBUSMENU-GLIB-WARNING **: Unable to get session
> bus: Could not connect: Connection refused
>
> (Pidgin:12897): libnotify-WARNING **: Failed to connect to proxy
>
> (Pidgin:12897): libindicate-ERROR **: Unable to get session bus: Could
> not connect: Connection refused Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare environment variables in terminal (`env`) and by running a script through desktop  shortcut.

**Script**

```
#!/bin/sh
env > ~/myenv
```

Check if value of DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS is different, because it seems to be the problem.

Comment: Turns out it was terminal's 'DISPLAY=:0' vs. Unity's 'DISPLAY=:0.0'